# Compare viewbag value with string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I assigned value to a ViewBag.Form in a controller

```
ViewBag.Form = "In";
```

Now, I want to compare the value with string in javascript. So I do it like this

```
 var form = "@ViewBag.Form";
if (form == "In")
{
//myCode
}
else
{
//myCode
}
```

But it always enter the else loop which mean form and ViewBag.Form doesnt match the value while it actually matched

Comment: Try `console.log('@ViewBag.Form')` in `else` to see what actually it holds.

Comment: This is not a good idea to use values stored in  `Viebag`'s in JS code. If you pass line breaks or `'` within a string, it will throw a syntax error.

Comment: @SeM do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @yusry it's more likely problem with your string value, because this code will work fine.

Comment: @yusry I suggest to add that property to your View page's model, store its value in hidden input or use `@Model`, then get its value with JS.

Comment: Where do you have this JS code? It has to be in your cshtml veiw, otherwise @ViewBag will not be visible.

Comment: The safest way: `var form = "@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Form)";` It will store special characters as plain text instead breaking the string.

Answer (score 0):

please take viewbag in JavaScript in single quote

like this '@ViewBag.Form'

```
var form = '@ViewBag.Form';
if (form == "In")
{
//myCode
}
else
{
//myCode
}
```

or 
assign ViewBag.Form value to hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="FormID" value="@ViewBag.Form" />

var form = document.getElementById('FormID'); //javascript
var form = $("#FormID").val(); //jQuery
    if (form == "In")
    {
    //myCode
    }
    else
    {
    //myCode
    }
```